# How to dynamically load an iFrame source and autofill input forms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, onload, autofill

I need to retrieve URL parameters (which I can do successfully) and based on one parameter, decide which iframe src to fill, then with other parameters auto fill the form that is created via the form src.  First issue is that I can't keep the page from going into an infinite loop.  It loads properly and shows the right iframe, but the infinite loop (load) needs to stop.  Second, I can't get the other parameters to autofill the input values.

Here is the code.  I hope you can help.  Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-    xhtml1-200000126/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Keep your jQuery up to date -->

<script  type="text/javascript">
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
var match,
    pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

urlParams = {};
while (match = search.exec(query))
   urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();


var test = urlParams["entry"];
var test2 = urlParams["test"];

function iframedirect(){
if (test=="sldk") {
    document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://na-sj09.marketo.com/lp/cochlearsandbox/UpgradeInterest_IFrameLandingPage.html";
    var f1 = frames['frame1'].document.forms['mktForm_1108'];
    f1.elements['FirstName'].value = test;
}else{
document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://na-sj09.marketo.com/lp/cochlearsandbox/CAM-UpgradeInterestForm_iFrameLandingPage2ndOption.html";
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body id="bodyId" class="mktEditable" align="center" >
<iframe id="frame1" src="" onload="iframedirect()" height="750px" width="620px"  scrolling="no"    frameborder="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is probably caused by the result of the function iframedirect().It changes the src of the iframe and triggers the [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event again and again.

You could use a variable to point out if the iframe has been loaded by iframedirect().

```
var test = urlParams["entry"];
var test2 = urlParams["test"]; 
var isLoadedByIFrameDirect = false;
function iframedirect() {
   if(!isLoadedByIFrameDirect) {
       if (test=="sldk") {
          document.getElementById("frame1").src = "url1";
          var f1 = frames['frame1'].document.forms['mktForm_1108'];
          f1.elements['FirstName'].value = test;
       }else{
          document.getElementById("frame1").src = "url2";
       }
       isLoadedByIFrameDirect = true;
   }
```

}

Comment: Implementing this did not stop the infinite loop.  Thanks for the idea.  You were right in realizing that I had a self referencing onload.  I needed to remove that, rather than try to stop it.  Thank you for actually putting your suggestion to code that can be easily copy and pasted.  So few people do that.  Novices really benefit from this.  I did solve the problem, and I will post it now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem is that I created a sel-freferencing onload event.  Bad idea.  To solve the issue, I needed to remove the onload from the iframe element.  I tried putting it in the Body before without luck.  But I might have screwed it up, so don't ignore that option if you have a similar situation.  I decided to do it with Javascript right after the function.  If you are a novice, the difference between Javascript onload and HTML onload can be found here

[W3Schools onload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

I still have not solved the "autofilling iframe form from url parameter" portion of this problem.  I will make an additional comment to this answer once I figure that out.

In any case, here is the code

```
function iframedirect() {
   if(!isLoadedByIFrameDirect) {
       if (test=="sldk") {
          document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://na-   sj09.marketo.com/lp/cochlearsandbox/UpgradeInterest_IFrameLandingPage.html";
          var f1 = frames['frame1'].document.forms['mktForm_1108'];
          f1.elements['FirstName'].value = test;
       }else{
          document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://na-sj09.marketo.com/lp/cochlearsandbox/CAM-UpgradeInterestForm_iFrameLandingPage2ndOption.html";
       }
       isLoadedByIFrameDirect = true;
   }
}
window.onload = iframedirect;
```